# SQL order by one column and and by the distinct values of another column

Tags: mysql

I have some rows that have among others, a column for hits and a column for manufacturer.

What I need to do is to order the row by hits and also by the distinct values of the manufacturers.

Let me give you an example to clear this up a bit, because I think I don't have the right words to describe what I want to do.

let's sat I have these rows (hits - manufacturers)

```
hits     manufacturers
----------------------
11       ManufacturerA
5        ManufacturerB
18       ManufacturerC
10       ManufacturerC
6        ManufacturerA
11       ManufacturerA
11       ManufacturerB
18       ManufacturerA
18       ManufacturerC
```

Now, what I'd like as result of the query is this

```
hits   manufacturers
--------------------
18     ManufacturerA
18     ManufacturerC
18     ManufacturerA
11     ManufacturerA
11     ManufacturerB
11     ManufacturerA
10     ManufacturerC
6      ManufacturerA
5      ManufacturerB
```

So, to conclude, the hits MUST be descending but if there are rows with the same amount of hits but with different manufacturers then these must order by ascending manufacturers BUT one from each until there are no more unique manufacturers and then repeat. One last example

lets say the ordering on hits has happened and this is what we got

```
hits   manufacturers
--------------------
18     ManufacturerB
18     ManufacturerB
18     ManufacturerA
18     ManufacturerC
18     ManufacturerC
18     ManufacturerA
18     ManufacturerA
```

I need this to become

```
hits   manufacturers
--------------------
18     ManufacturerA
18     ManufacturerB
18     ManufacturerC
18     ManufacturerA
18     ManufacturerB
18     ManufacturerC
18     ManufacturerA
```

Can this be done and how? And if it can, how expensive is the query gonna be? Is it worth it

Thank you

p.s. I tried to explain it as best as i could :)

Comment: actually there are 33 columns. Right now I'm just sorting by the hits column. Why do you think a 3rd column plays any part in what I'm trying to do? just assume there are other columns as well, some of which are unique id's

Comment: What is your primary key

Comment: my primary key is an auto increment - MEDIUMINT datatype - with length/set 8

Comment: Please edit your question accordingly.